# Design an own calendar view....Where to get started?

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm making a reservation system in PHP and MySQL. So far the resevation system is working, it shows the item which is reserved and between what dates.

All I need to do now is to show this in a nice calendar-look view so the user can see which items are reserved for which date and time, it's alot better than echoing out the starting and ending dates of the reservation items and order by the dates... Something like an agenda...

I'm looking around on the internet now for a while, but not with much success.

If someone happens to knows any good tutorials around, I'd love to hear.

Comment: [Why reinvent the wheel](http://www.php-calendar.com/) when [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=calendar+php&aq=0&oq=calendar+php&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active) can point you to a ton of tuts and _existing calendars_?

Comment: I need to create an own design, echoing out database information in a view, which can be monitored later on screens. Best way to do it is to create it myself, but I don't know where to start. Looking for tutorials the whole day now, but nothing really added value so far.

Comment: IMO, the best tutorial is still trying to read existing code, see how others do things, and what the pro's and con's of each decision might be to your specific case. When in doubt, you can always use a framework, like ZendFW. This helps you to build fairly large DB-driven applications without having to worry about _where to start_. Just `$application->bootstrap();` and it's all OO (MVC) from there on end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great 'jQuery Week Calendar', perfect for my need! Events are set by single line of codes. By writing one line to this eventfile when I'm reserving an item, the reservation will be shown on the calendar by day and hour.

EDIT: The calendar can be found here: https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar

Comment: For future purpose it'd be great if you could post a link so others facing the same problem could take a use of your answer. I'm guessing that [**this is it**](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar), but please edit your answer and add it there.